# the disabled checkbox gets functioned when clicking on its row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

. .On click button the checkbox gets disabled, but i have also added a function for getting checked or unchecked when clicked on row. .but the problem is after clicking the button the checkbox gets disabled but when i click the row . . .it gets unchecked. I have added the code in JSfiddle. .its not functioning at all.I dono much in .js.So please help me

this is the code

```
function selectRow(row){
var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;

 if(firstInput.disabled==false && firstInput.checked==true){firstInput.checked =true;} 
 else if(firstInput.disabled==true){firstInput.checked=true;}}
```

html code is

in js fiidle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zain0788/Vg3Y5/4/)

Comment: your  jsfiddle code is not working. shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: selectRow is not defined`

Comment: fiddle w/o error http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vg3Y5/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be as simple as

```
function selectRow(row) {
    var chk = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    if (!chk.disabled) {
        chk.checked = !chk.checked;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pkmxm/), [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pkmxm/2/)

*Note: even though you have used jQuery tag there is no jQuery used in the script*